# Using Carto, changes to legend not reflected on map

Tags: legend, cartodb

## Problem

I'm working on a map in Carto and I'm trying to tweak the labels in the legend. Every time I share and then update the map layer in the builder:

- The changes are not reflected even though I can see the new text in the editor for that specific layer `untitled_table_20`
- When I go to my public page, I can see that it mentions my map hasn't actually been changed for quite a while.

## Dropbox link: [Carto file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fm07fy7nt2fm005/2017%20Total%20Solar%20Eclipse%20Path%20%28on%202017-06-27%20at%2017.37.11%29%20%281%29.carto?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older CartoDB maps made using Editor, you may have to duplicate your map in order to edit it in their newer Builder tool. Making the changes was pretty straightforward after that.

Comment: Is the issue being solved then? (also the map you have shared is made with Editor instead of BUILDER)